# Detecting calendar items created on local machine only

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, office-interop

I am writing an Outlook plugin which needs to track the creation of calendar items. I am using the following code to detect when something is added to the calendar by the user:

```
            foreach (Account acc in _outlookApplication.Session.Accounts)
        {
            var calendar = acc.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            var itemsCalendar = calendar.Items;
            itemsCalendar.ItemAdd += new ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(OnMeetingCreated);
        }
```

This works well on the local machine and the event fires properly. However, if the user has two machines with the same email account set up, this event will be fired on the secondary machine as well once Outlook on the secondary machine syncs and downloads the newly created Meeting items by the user on the primary machine.

Is there a way to somehow ignore meetings that were not created by the user on the local machine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALL data is created on the local PC, whether in a .pst or .ost file.  If your add-in is creating the item and you want to ignore or process that item in the ItemAdd event than you will need to manage an in-memory collection of items that you want to compare against.

Alternatively, you can add a machine specific token to a custom property in the item and use that as a flag to compare against.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the calendar items are created manually by users or by accepting a meeting invitation etc, Is there a way to intercept this process and add a unique token to the properties before the ItemAdd event could be fired?

Comment: Yes, just handle the Application.NewInspector event and setup event handlers as necessary for the AppointmentItem object (e.g. PropertyChange, Close, etc.).

Comment: Ah, didn't know about that one. Thanks!